# How do I configure eclipse with the egit plugin so that I can open files in something other than the text editor?

Tags: php, eclipse, git, eclipse-pdt, egit

I have cloned a project from a git repo into eclipse Helios using the egit plugin.  This is a php project, and I have eclipse PDT which works fine with projects pulled from svn using subclipse and projects start new.

The problem is that the egit workspace files with .php extension are not loading into the php editor, and if you right click on one, the only useful option is to open them using the text editor, so there's no php perspective functionality.

What am I missing?

Just in case it matters, this is running on a Win Vista 64bit machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turned out to be this:  I used Import, Project from Git, selected the git repo where I had made the sandbox.  In the next dialogue, I Chose Import Existing Project.  Picked the working directory that was already on disk.

Answer (score 0):

The real problem seems to be that Eclipse does not understand the project has a PHP nature. 
If the project was pushed on repo by someone who did not worked on it with Eclipse, it might not have the `.project` file in it, or simply it may be there, but without such nature.

Try looking at the .project file (if any): it should contain something like:

```
<natures>
 <nature>org.eclipse.php.core.PHPNature</nature>
</natures>
```

The .project file should be in your workspace under the project root directory.

Comment: I setup the project in git but it predates my use of eclipse.  I don't know a lot about eclipse, but this gives me something to look into.

Comment: Let me know if it does the job!